# lazy newb pack wont start

Tags: dwarf-fortress

DF window and process closing after TWBT %version% was printed in the console. 
I am using lazy newb pack, on my other laptop all working fine, so it's obviously laptop related problem.

What kind of problem is it? I disable antivirus and firewall already.
Does anyone have this problem?

laptop specs:

windows 7 professional, mcaffee antivirus, Symantec hard drive encryption, 8 Gb of RAM, i5 proc (6th gen), intel hd graphics 520

I'm totally sure this is a laptop related problem because I did the same sequence on my another laptop and lnp works totally fine.

Important addition:
vanilla df without any add-ons and graphic layouts works fine.

[image: the problem behavior]

Comment: Are you sure you followed the instructions properly to install it?

Comment: yes, i think i install it properly

Comment: I sincerely doubt it's a laptop issue.  Even if it is, though, you haven't given us any information *about* the laptop.

Comment: Could someone please give me any explanation why do I have downvotes? it's really helpful not only be truncated by society but also have an explanation what u did wrong.

Comment: @Frank, what kind of information do u need? it's dell latitude e7470, with macaffee antivirus and Symantec hard drive encryption utility.

Comment: It's specs, what operating system you're running, why you think it's the laptop.  More detail about everything.  This is stuff you should have as part of your question, so edit it with the additional info.

Comment: @Frank, I added the gif with the problem and try to reveal as much laptop specs as I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a problem with TWBT that prevent the screen from resizing. Now I'm using TWBT legacy with resolution presets. When I'm trying to resize the window manually there is still an error (no mention in the log or console) that causes window closing.

But it still does the trick for me.

Comment: I hope my post will help someone :)